# How to get values and also number of rows having that particular value, which is derived from multiple condtions on pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have pandas dataframe

```
Id  drove   swimmed walked  winPerc
0   247.3   1050    782.4   1
1   37.65   1072    119.6   0.04
2   93.73   1404    3248    1
3   95.88   1069    21.49   0.1146
4   0       1034    640.8   0
5   128.1   1000    1016    0.9368

average 100.4433333 1104.833333 971.3816667 
Min     0           1000        21.49   
max     247.3       1404        3248`
```

winPerc = 1 implies that the player has won with 1st rank, similarly winPerc = 0 tells us that player came last

```
print("The person who ends up winning the match usually drives {:.2f} , swims {:.2f} meters, has a walked {} meters".format(df.set_index('drove')['winPerc'].idxmax(),df.set_index('swimmed')['winPerc'].idxmax(),df.set_index('walked')['winPerc'].idxmax()))
```

for this I am getting:-

> IndexError: tuple index out of range

What I want is as you can see in the above dataframe, the rows with id 0 and 2 have winPerc = 1 I should get the response like :
`The person who ends up winning the match usually drives 170.52 , swims 1227 meters, has a walked 2015.2 meters` And if there were multiple records with winPerc =1 then I should get the values accordingly

Also there can be players who might not have driven (drove = 0) and,

have won the game (winPerc = 1)

```
print("{} number of confident Players won without driving".format(len(df['drove'].min()['winPerc'].idxmax())))
```

For this I am getting this error:-

> IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.

If *in case* there is no row which has column value of min() or max() or mean(), then I should take the values which have near by values which are close to that particular case.

Thanks in advance and let me know if I have to explain more. :)

Comment: I will delete my previous answer but please update your question to specify what you actually want since it is unclear given your response to my answer. Provide examples of expected output for each thing that you want to do.

Comment: your answer to my second problem was correct (y) Please share that again :)
Coming back to 1st problem,
as you can see in the above dataframe, the rows with id 0 and 2 have winPerc = 1
I should get the response like :
`The person who ends up winning the match usually drives 170.52 , swims 1227 meters, has a walked 2015.2 meters`

And if there were multiple records with winPerc =1 then I should get the values accordingly

Comment: Please update your question with expected output rather than adding a comment :)

Answer (score 0):

I copied the first print without changing anything and it works fine for me:

`The person who ends up winning the match usually drives 247.30 , swims 1050.00 meters, has a walked 782.4 meters`.

When you use `.format()` and get `IndexError: tuple out of range` it means that you are calling it with too few variables.

---

For the second problem you need to filter your `DataFrame`. This can be accomplished in different ways, using boolean masking is a common one.

```
>> drove_is_0 = df["drove"] == df['drove'].min()
>> is_winner =  df['winPerc'] == df['winPerc'].idxmax()
```

Then apply your filters to your `DataFrame`:

```
>> filtered = df[drove_is_0 & is_winner]
```

Lastly print:

```
>> print("{} number of confident Players won without driving".format(len(filtered)))
1 number of confident Players won without driving
```

---

OP has clarified that the first question was not about the raised `IndexError` but rather also about filtering. They want to filter the `df` on the column `winPerc` where the value is `1` and then calculate `mean` values for different columns. I will use boolean masking as showed above for consistency:

```
>> is_winner = df["winPerc"] == 1

>> mean_driven_winner = df[is_winner]["drove"].mean()
>> mean_swimmed_winner = df[is_winner]["swimmed"].mean()
>> mean_walked_winner = df[is_winner]["walked"].mean()

>> print("The person who ends up winning the match usually drives {:.2f} , swims {:.2f} meters, has a walked {} meters".format(
    mean_driven_winner, mean_swimmed_winner, mean_walked_winner)
)

The person who ends up winning the match usually drives 170.52 , swims 1227.00 meters, has a walked 2015.2 meters
```

Comment: thanks for replying, as you can see there are 2 records of winners
`Id  drove   swimmed walked  winPerc
0   247.3   1050    782.4   1
2   93.73   1404    3248    1`

I want to get the mean of the columns where the winPerc is 1

Comment: updated with answer to first question after your clarification